# Convert data attrs to get/post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert data attributes to valid post (or get) data?

```
$('#nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var params = $(this).data();
    $.get({
        type: "get",
        url: "/view/",
        data: params
    });
})
```

I get this error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/Site1/%5Bobject%20Object%5D/ 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Comment: show your html.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/),

```
$('#nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var params = $(this).data();
    params = $.param(params);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        url: "/view/",
        data: params
    });
})
```

**EDIT:**

Actually the problem is you're using [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method like [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

`$.get()` doesn't accepts ajax settings object. Change it to $.ajax() than you don't need to use params.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5cYdK/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$('#nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var params = $(this).data();
    $.get("/view/",params,function(){
        //success callback
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html it makes answering this more difficult but try something like this. $.post('YourUrl', { paramName : $("elementID").val(), paramName2 : $("#elementId").attr("data")}, function(data){ DoSuccessHere });

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery `get` function takes an object for its data parameter, i.e.

```
$('#nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var params = {
        param1: 'foo',
        param2: 'bar';
    }
    $.get({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/view/',
        data: params
    });
});
```

You can assign multiple values from multiple data sources in this way, e.g.

```
var params = {
    id: $(this).id(),
    name: $(this).attr('name');
}
```